# Something Similar to RAPL for non Sandy Bridge/xeon processors

Tags: linux, cpu, intel, processor, energy

First post ever here.

I wanted to know if there was something similar to the Running Average Power Limit for other processors(Intel i7) that aren't Sandy Bridge or Xeon Processors as the machine im working on in the lab.

For those who do not know. I pulled this description to bring you up to speed.

"RAPL(Running Average Power Limit) interface provides platform software
with the ability to monitor, control, and get notifications on SOC
power consumptions."

What I am looking for in particular is to acquire energy consumption measurements on a processor's individual cores after running some code like Matrix Multiplication or Vector Addition. Temperature would be excellent too but that's another question for another day(lm-sensors is a bit puzzling to me)

Thanks and Take Care.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Late answer on this: There's PowerTOP on Linux, but that works for Laptops only as it needs the battery discharge rate for that. It can display Watts per process, but don't ask me how accurate that is (personally I think there might be some problems with that). IIRC it counts the number of CPU wakeups from a CPU sleep state to calculate the energy consumption per process. Also, for AMD processors there's the fam15h_power driver in the lm-sensors software package. For rather new (2011 and newer) Bulldozer AMD CPUs you can get the energy consumption that way.

Note that RAPL does not provide energy consumption per core on a multicore CPU, but only for the whole CPU. You can get the energy consumption of core and non-core (like integrated graphics) separately, but per-core is not possible.

Comment: Sincere thanks I actually found out how a while ago. 
I just read from the coretemp files. 
I found that it only takes an avg of 32 microseconds to do the read.